# Closing boto ec2 connection

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto

How to close a boto ec2 connection?

I opened the connection using:

```
conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region(region, aws_access_key_id=access_key, aws_secret_access_key=secret_key)
```

I tried the close() function but I don't think it tears down the connection.

```
conn.close()
```

Output on running close() : `[DEBUG]:closing all HTTP connections`

Even after closing, it gets all the reservation

```
reservations = conn.get_all_instances()
```

I was looking at these doc http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ec2_tut.html but couldn't find the documentation for close() function.

I would really appreciate if someone can help me out here.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boto manages a pool of HTTP connections and attempts to reuse them to save on connection costs (especially the HTTPS handshake).  Using the `close` method does allow the connection to be garbage collected but as soon as you attempt another request on the same EC2Connection object a new connection will be created for you which is why the subsequent request still works.

To add to this, I guess my advise would be not to worry too much about closing connections because boto is trying pretty hard to manage those connections efficiently and reuse them when possible.

Are you running into specific issues wrt to open connections?

Comment: No I'm not running into any specify issue w.r.t open connections. I was just being pre-cautious. Thank you so much.